# How to set "123" mode as default mode in iOS keyboard Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

Code to set the keyboard's overall type:

```
self.Value.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault
```

How can I set the default keyboard's mode from "ABC to "123" at launch? Or even only "123" mode.

Any ideas?

[image: As default mode]

[image: Only this mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Storyboard click on the textfield and then go to the attribute, there you will find the keyboard from the you can select the number pad or number and punctuation[image: See the image for more information]

Comment: Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Please set UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation.

`self.Value.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`